# how to manage table content with css

Tags: html, css

I have created a table with `width="610"`, but there was overflow that went outside of the boundary of the table. I want to prevent this action using only CSS, but I am unsure of how to do that

HTML

```
<p></p>
<div id="content">
  <div id="fill">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" style="width: 610px;" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="width: 3%;">
            <p></p>
          </td>
          <td style="width: 97%;">
            <p><a href=""></a></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The content in the `<a href="">` expands to outside of the `div` content.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please add the relevant HTML markup and CSS code, so that somebody can understand your problem and help you out.

Comment: Remove the `width=610`

Comment: Could you add your code, and describe the problem (and what you want the code to do) in more detail?

Answer (score 2):

The table's `width` attributes are by default interpreted as `min-width`. When the cell contents exceeds the specified table/cell width, then the table/cell width are stretched accordingly to its contents. To fix it, override the default [table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) property:

```css
.table1 {
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.table1 td {
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zEDcU/

Comment: Probably this is what he/she wanted to ask for.

Comment: Thanks, yes probably it is.

Comment: thanks for answer, i tried to use that syntax but the height fall out to full screan.

Answer (score 1):

give the table a class or an id

```
<table class="class_name" id="id_name"></table>
```

then style it with css

```
#id_name {width:100%}
.class_name {width:100%}
```

Answer (score 1):

To the head:

```
<style type="css">
  table.my { width:610px; ... }
    table.my tr { ... }
</style>
```

To the body:

```
<table class="my">
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give your table class and use this class like this:

Table:

```
   .table1
```

Table Row:

```
.table1 tr
```

Table td:

```
.table1 tr td
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables have cells. Each cell has width, padding, border and margin like everyone html element.
To Remove the initial margin/padding of cells you can use . Then you can use td { } in your CSS to add custrom styles to the cells or if you want something more specific you have to add classes or ids to your cells and then use CSS to style them.

Comment: Thats not entirely true. Table cells do *not* have margins, see: [17.5 Visual layout of table contents](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-layout): "*Internal table elements do not have margins.*".

Answer (score 0):

at first you need to set the width of the table using css(style). When setting width directly in the HTML tag wich will automatically increases the width as the content increase, especially Images. you can also controll the issue by setting width to the content if its something like an Image.